# error while using parseFloat "An invalid form control with name='field_name' is not focusable."

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have two text boxes in html **type=number**

```
<input data-sign="BHD " type="number" class="widthinput input__field input__field--yoshiko validation-passed" value="" name="special_price" id="special_price">
<input data-sign="BHD " value="" type="number" class="required-entry validate-zero-or-greater input__field input__field--yoshiko validation-passed" name="price" id="price">
```

and here is my js code for checking

```
if(parseFloat(jQuery('#special_price').val()) >= parseFloat(jQuery('#price').val())){
    console.log(parseFloat(jQuery('#special_price').val()));
    console.log(parseFloat(jQuery('#price').val()));
    alert("You can't enter special price greater than price");
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

When i enter values like

> price : 160 , special_price : 90

this js condition working fine but when i enter values like

> price 250.750, special price 55.350

this condition fails and giving me error in console

```
An invalid form control with name='price' is not focusable.
An invalid form control with name='special_price' is not focusable.
```

I am on chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, Please check your jquery library. Refer    [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/54mau116/)

Or Adding a `novalidate` attribute to the form will help:

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
```

**Update**

The **number** type has a `step` value controlling which numbers are valid (along with `max` and `min`), which defaults to **1**. This value is also used by implementations for the stepper buttons (i.e. pressing up increases by `step`).

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Simply change this value to whatever is appropriate. For money, two decimal places are probably expected:

(I'd also set min=0 if it can only be positive)

If you'd prefer to allow any number of decimal places, you can use `step="any"` (though for currencies, I'd recommend sticking to 0.01). In Chrome & Firefox, the stepper buttons will increment / decrement by 1 when using `any`, and see [the relevant spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-step))

Here's a playground showing how various steps affect various input types:

```html
<form>
  <input type=number step=1 /> Step 1 (default)<br />
  <input type=number step=0.01 /> Step 0.01<br />
  <input type=number step=any /> Step any<br />
  <input type=range step=20 /> Step 20<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=60 /> Step 60 (default)<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=1 /> Step 1<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=any /> Step any<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=0.001 /> Step 0.001<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=3600 /> Step 3600 (1 hour)<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=86400 /> Step 86400 (1 day)<br />
  <input type=datetime-local step=70 /> Step 70 (1 min, 10 sec)<br />
</form>
```

Comment: i can't add novalidate i need validations

Comment: i think the issue is type="number" that don't accept float numbers

Comment: try to make type="text" and check input is number or not with js function

Comment: yeah i post my answer as well i am doing that way but still confused why the float is not acceptable on type="number"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was **type="number"** when i changed it into **type="text"** and i am validating number from js its working fine now.